# Bold Typewriter Type fonts

Tags: fonts, bold, typewriter, metafont

I found out that there are `cmbtt10` and `cmttb10` fonts available. Unfortunately they are not used until I activate them with the `\font` macro, so just searching for those fonts is not possible.

The `cmbtt10` seems too thick. The `cmttb10` looks quite what I need, but its characters are too wide. Both seems to be a low resolution font.

I also learned that these fonts are created with METAFONT the first time they are activated, but need the Typewriter Type font source. Are there other fonts that are created in the same manner from Typewriter Type? Is it possible to create a better resolution (like 600~1200 DPI)? How difficult is to define my own modification?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest Latin Modern Mono Light family. In Plain TeX:

```
\font\tt=rm-lmtl10
\font\itt=rm-lmtlo10
\font\btt=rm-lmtk10
\font\bitt=rm-lmtko10
\tt   Hello\par
\itt  Hello\par
\btt  Hello\par
\bitt Hello\par
\bye
```

[image]

In LaTeX, it is `lmtt` family in `OT1` font encoding. See `ot1lmtt.fd` for more information.

---

Latin Modern fonts are available in Type1 and OpenType. Usually we use the Type1 fonts with pdfTeX, dvipdfm(x) and Dvips engine/driver, and they are installed for pdfTeX, dvipdfm(x) and Dvips, respectively. Type1 fonts are vector fonts, they can be freely scaled with out loss of quality.

If you use a font made by MetaFont, you can specify the resolution when calling pdfTeX, dvipdfm(x) or Dvips.

Use `\pdfpkresolution` to specify the PK font resolution for pdfTeX. For example,

```
\pdfpkresolution=1200
```

Use `-r` command line option to specify the PK font resolution for dvipdfm(x). For example,

```
dvipdfmx -r 1200 foo.dvi
```

And use `-D` command line option to specify the PK font resolution for Dvips. For example,

```
dvips -D 1200 foo.dvi
```

Comment: Note: Latin Modern fonts are very similar to Computer Modern.

Comment: Also, LM is available in other encodings -- T1 of course, but also QX and others.

Comment: Actually I don't need the document to be in a fixed DPI, I was only curious on how to manipulate that kind of font generation. But this Latin Modern, if it is really close to Computer Modern, will be perfect for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the typewriter font of the [Bera](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/bera.html) family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{beramono}

\begin{document}
\texttt{This is just a \textbf{test}.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to do this in plain TeX? `\font\ttbf=beramonob`? I don't quite like the font face though: It's another font, not the cmtt font.

Comment: Sorry, @AdamLS, I am not familiar with fonts in plain TeX. And true, it is another font.

Comment: Bera Mono in Plain TeX: `fvmr8t`, `fvmro8t`, `fvmb8t` and `fvmbo8t`. (see `beramono.sty` and then `t1fvm.fd`)