# Using \ttfamily with \bfseries (or how to enable bold in fixed-width font)

Tags: listings, bold, typewriter

I'm using `listings` package, and I've added `basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize`. However, when I do that, the keywords from the embedded source-code are not bold anymore.

I figured that `\ttfamily` together with `\bfseries` does not work.

And then I found a [FAQ about bold-extras](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-bold-extras), and I tried adding `\usepackage[bold-extras]`, and it didn't work either. What does that package do? Should I just ignore it and move on?

And then I finally found [Using bold/italic text inside listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/using-bold-italic-text-inside-listings), which may be a duplicate to this one, but was a lot harder to find. I also found [Bold Typewriter Type fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/bold-typewriter-type-fonts), which got me more confused.

So, what should I do in order to get a bold fixed-width font for use within `listings`?

Using `pdflatex` from texlive-2010.

Comment: You need to use a font which has a bold tt family. Check http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html. AFAIK `lmodern` should be ok.

Comment: The Computer Modern Typewriter font family doesn't have a boldface variant. You can say `\usepackage{lmodern}`, maybe with the option `lighttt` for better distinction between medium weight and boldface letters in typewriter type. Or `\usepackage{beramono}`, for example, that provides a boldface variant.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As Martin mentioned in the comment, you need a font which provides such a combination. The following example shows that the font courier has this combination implemented instead of Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

% Default Computer Modern font (no bold implemented)
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries]
y:=2
\end{lstlisting}

% Using Courier font
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries]
y:=2
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: The first "y:=2" is not rendered as bold, but the second one is.]

Comment: And sorry my ignorance, but how do I use this? Just adding `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}`?

Comment: @DenilsonSá: If you only need the typewriter font of courier you can use this command.

Comment: The solution with `lmodern` (see Ulrike answer) looks much better than this `pcr` version; besides it gives a font that is consistent with the default fixed font.

Answer (score 27):

A different option is to use the Latin Modern fonts, that sport a fully featured boldface typewriter font. They have also another feature, because they can use a lighter version for the medium weight:

```
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
```

Let's compare a couple of examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

Abc {\ttfamily abc \bfseries abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}

\begin{document}

Abc {\ttfamily abc \bfseries abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Where the distinction between the weights in monospaced fonts is crucial, this can be an option.

This will work out of the box with `listings` and the option

```
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
```

will suffice after having loaded `lmodern` with or without the `lighttt` option.

Comment: Is there a reason to also load the `fontenc` package?  Wouldn't `lmodern` suffice?

Comment: @A.Ellett I do it just by habit (I'm European, you know). It doesn't harm and makes available many more glyphs than OT1.

Comment: I prefer lighttt look, but it's turns out that when there are comments in the listing it throws errors I guess it lacks italic variant? Is there a simple workaround for it? lmodern without the lighttt option works just fine.

Comment: @slawek Maybe a follow-up question with a MWE is better

Comment: `lighttt` messed up the italic style and now it shows it as tilted.

Comment: @Atcold I still have yet to find a solution to this. The answers from your post did not help since I have hundreds of thousands of listings and I do NOT want to go through and change them all :(

Comment: @TheProgrammer You just need `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}` in the document preamble

Comment: @egreg But the ttfamily I’m using *is* the lighttt lmodern variant. This is excellent, except for the fact that it overwrites the italic font face with the slanted version. I guess this is just a limitation of the font…

Comment: @TheProgrammer There is no Latin Modern Mono bold italic, just bold slanted.

Comment: @egreg, we were talking about Latin Modern Mono italic, which exists for the non-light version but it's inexistent for the light version. (Maybe we are talking about the same thing but I didn't get it.)

Answer (score 15):

Bold-extra is not a package you load, it is a collection of fonts. But as this are metafont (bitmap) fonts I wouldn't recommend using them. Better switch either to the lmodern fonts, or use the luximono or the beramono-typewriter font:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{luximono}
%\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\begin{document}
abc 
\ttfamily abc \bfseries abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both answers are good. I'm accepting the other one because it seems to allow more fine-grained control. But, still, if I could I would accept these two answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use poors-man-bold `\pmb`  from the package `amsbsy`:

```
\usepackage{amsbsy}
[...]
\begin{lstlisting}[keywordstyle=\pmb,language=C]
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: You of course can, but LaTeX is no longer a poor man having no bold typewriter fonts. As you can see from the other answers, the font options are numerous. And `\pmb` renders really badly.

Comment: Even though it's not the best solution nowadays, it is still a nice trick that might come handy someday.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by egreg loads new fonts that seems to change fonts for the whole document -- not only in listings (in my document it changed the font used in paragraphs).

The accepted answer uses `pcr` -- some may find it not very beautiful. You could use `lmtt` instead.

Below is the version that uses `lmtt` and additionally wraps the font-change command into the new command.

Put into the preamble of your document:

```
\newcommand*{\ttfamilywithbold}{\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont}
```

Now, use it like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamilywithbold,language=python,mathescape]
b_reach`= $C$
while (b_reach $\neq$ b_reach`):
  b_reach = b_reach`
  b_reach`= b_reach $\cup$ b_pred_b(b_reach, $P$, $\pgraph$)
if b_reach` contains an initial state:
  return 'Yes'
return 'No'
\end{lstlisting}
```

You will get:

[image: result with ttfamilywithbold]

And compare it with non-bold version (that has `\ttfamily` instead of `ttfamilywithbold`):

[image]

The main source: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/25251#25251)

Comment: Please, add `\usepackage{upquote}` to your preamble 