# listings doesn't print my keywords bold in lstlisting

Tags: listings, highlighting, keywords

I've got the following problem: I want to print a listing with the listings package and lstlisting:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Haskell,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\bfseries]
class Show a where
  show :: a -> String
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

But in the result I get, the keywords are not printed in bold font! This problem does not occur when I remove the basic style key-value-pair, but without this style, the listings look ugly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33041/21891

Comment: Standard CM fonts does not include boldface tt

Comment: Just add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Do you want the keywords in bold typewriter font or just bold?

Comment: Both in typewriter and bold

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
\usepackage{courier}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Might not be the prettiest of fonts, have a look at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html, it will tell you if a given font supports boldface