# What is the least invasive way to set the font for listings?

Tags: fonts, listings

As has [been](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/using-bold-italic-text-inside-listings) [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/using-ttfamily-with-bfseries-or-how-to-enable-bold-in-fixed-width-font) [often](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127993/listings-doesnt-print-my-keywords-bold-in-lstlisting) [enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515120/latex-lstlisting-not-highlighting-keywords-when-basic-style-is-ttfamily), to get bold keywords in `lstlisting` environments, one has to use a different typewriter font. Most answers suggest to include this or that package.

If just including a package changes the font, then the package must be applying some magic in the background to install itself. And unless the package was specifically made for listings, this means it potentially also changes other stuff.

How can I use another font in my listings while being sure that nothing else is affected, or at least that nothing but the default typewriter font is changed?

Comment: Good font packages such as `DejaVuSansMono` or `beramono` just change the meaning of `\ttdefault`, which is just what you want; they also allow to specify a scaling factor. The package `tgcursor` does the same, but unfortunately also changes the meaning of `\bfdefault`; just add `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}` after loading `tgcursor`.

Comment: @egreg I think Arian wants to use a different font for listings *without* changing `\ttdefault`...

Comment: Changing `\ttdefault` is acceptable, as Herbert said it doesn't make much sense to use different monospaced fonts. But my work has to conform to a given style (cls file is provided), and I want to change it as little as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an excellent question. Many answers to questions about `listings` on this site tell you to load along with the `fontenc` package with option `T1` (which is fine) along with a package such as `courier` or `beramono` in order to have access to boldface typewriter fonts. However, packages like `beramono` and `courier` change the default typewriter font family globally, which may not be what you want.

If you want a certain font only inside listings, you should simply select it in the `basicstyle` key.

```
basicstyle = \fontfamily{desired-font}\selectfont ...
```

I suggest you define a macro to easily select the font in question (see below).
You should still load the `fontenc` package with option `T1`, but don't load `beramono` or the likes of it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

% macro to select a scaled-down version of Bera Mono (for instance)
\makeatletter
\newcommand\BeraMonottfamily{%
  \def\fvm@Scale{0.85}% scales the font down
  \fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont% selects the Bera Mono font
}
\makeatother

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\BeraMonottfamily, 
  frame=single,
}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Computer Modern typewriter font, as usual}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,caption=listing typeset with Bera Mono]
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let's say I know which font I want (eg, from here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html). How do I know what to put in `\fontfamily{}`?

Comment: @Arian See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118969/quickest-way-to-search-for-valid-fontfamily-arguments and http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/typographics.html

Answer (score 2):

It makes no real sense to use a Monofont for listings and the default CM mono for typewriter text. Use it for all `\ttfamily` and it looks nicer. It is one of the typographers rule not to mix a lot of different fonts.
A scaled version of DejaVu Mono:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{DejaVuSansMono}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP doesn't want the default typewriter font to be Bera Mono everywhere in the document, only in listings.