# Get a font like in alltt from listings

Tags: listings

How can I get a portion of my document that uses the listings package to display in the font that is used in alltt?

Right now I have

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language = SAS]
proc hpsplit data = autompg2 seed = 123 plots = zoomedtree(nodes = ("0") depth = 2 
     fracprec = 2 predictorprec = 2);
  class origin cylinders;
 model mpg = cylinders displacement weight acceleration year origin;
   output out=mpgout;
    rules file = "\path\mpgrule.txt";
run;

proc means data = mpgout;
 class _NODE_;
 var MPG;
run;
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: How about `{\ttfamily...} `?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Where would I put that? I will add a code sample to my question.

Comment: `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}`

Comment: Try adding the option `basicstyle = \ttfamily` to the options for your `lstlisting` environment (or add `\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily}` to your preamble.

Comment: Does this answer your question such that we can close this question as solved?

Comment: @siracusa Yes. But I can't accept it as it is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @moewe in case you want to add an answer, please do; otherwise please close as solved in the comments

Comment: @siracusa Added an answer. I'd also be fine with closing as a duplicate, but a (admittedly short) search did not reveal anything except https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174892/35864.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get typewriter font in `listings` with `basicstyle = \ttfamily`. To enable this setting globally, you can use

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
```