# Emphasise a particular keyword in minted

Tags: minted

In minted, how do I highlight a particular set of keywords by making them bold. Say for example consider the MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{manni}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{java}
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The above generates this:
[image]
Now, whenever I use the keyword `class`, it should be in bold. How do I do that?

Comment: This is out of control for `minted`, which delegates the job to Pygmentize and its lexers. A Python forum would be better, I guess.

Comment: On the other hand, `class` is already printed boldface; try adding `\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}` to realize it. The fact is that the usual Computer Modern Typewriter fonts don't have a boldface variant.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/using-ttfamily-with-bfseries-or-how-to-enable-bold-in-fixed-width-font for the font problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such option with `minted`. But with `listings` it is easy. you can use

```
escapechar=!,   %% use any character as you wish
```

or

```
moredelim=[is][\bfseries\color{magenta}]{`}{`},   %% same as above
```

Or

```
escapeinside={*@}{@*}     %% Use as *@ \bfseries class @*
```

etc.

Here is some sample:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listings} % for code snippets

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  backgroundcolor=\color{olive!10},
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=10pt,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  escapechar=!,
  moredelim=[is][\bfseries\color{magenta}]{`}{`},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=!,]
!\bfseries\color{blue} class! Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
`class`
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In fact you *can* do the same for minted, you just have to adapt either the stylesheet or the lexer (both are written in Python).

Comment: Minted now supports escapeinside, although it is fragile in some cases.

Answer (score 11):

The `class` keyword is already printed boldface. The problem is that the default Computer Modern Typewriter doesn't have a boldface variant, see [Using \ttfamily with \bfseries (or how to enable bold in fixed-width font)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/using-ttfamily-with-bfseries-or-how-to-enable-bold-in-fixed-width-font) for details.

Indeed, if we follow one of the suggestions, the example file

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{manni}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{java}
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

will print

[image]

However, here's a set of macros for overriding the style for particular keywords (thanks to Marco Daniel for suggesting the idea).

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{manni}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \AddWordToMinted { m m }
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_xminted_highlight_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\prop_new:N \g_xminted_highlight_prop

\AtBeginDocument{
  \cs_set_eq:NN \xminted_pydo:nn \PY
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \xminted_newpydo:nn #1 #2
   {
    \xminted_pydo:nn { #1 } { \prop_get:Nn \g_xminted_highlight_prop { #2 } #2 }
   }
  \cs_set_eq:NN \PY \xminted_newpydo:nn
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

%% Just to experiment
\AddWordToMinted{class}{\sffamily}
\AddWordToMinted{void}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{java}
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that as of September 2014, `\prop_get:Nn` has been renamed to `\prop_item:Nn`

Answer (score 4):

Try using *escapeinside* option available in the latest minted release v2.1 from 09/09/2015. See the documentation here http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf. 
The documentation of *escapeinside* says the following.

> Escape to LATEX between the two characters specified in (string). All code
>   between the two characters will be interpreted as LATEX and typeset accordingly.
>   This allows for additional formatting. The escape characters need not be identical. Special LATEX characters must be escaped when they are used as the escape characters (for example, escapeinside=#\%). Requires Pygments 2.0+.

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{py}
  def f(x):
     y = x|\colorbox{green}{**}|2
     return y
\end{minted}
```

resulted in
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Posting full examples instead of some fragment of code is most times more useful