# How to use lstlisting "moredelim" inside quoted text [RESOLVED, but with possible caveats for others]

Tags: listings

**update**: Arun's answer, below, works for me, since I'm not using syntax highlighting anyway.  Thanks!

Here's my original question:

I use the following setting to allow me to mark text as bold within an lstlisting environment by putting three asterisks at the beginning and end of the bolded section:

```
 \lstset{moredelim=[is][\bfseries]{***}{***}}
```

This works find most of the time, but fails when I try to use it within quoted text.  For example, the following works:

```
 \begin{lstlisting}
 this is a ***test***!
 \end{lstlisting}
```

but the following doesn't:

```
 \begin{lstlisting}
 "this is a ***test***!"
 \end{lstlisting}
```

The second form simply prints literal asterisks.  Is there a way to turn off the special behaviour of lstlisting when within quotes?

Bryan

**edit**: I've added a complete minimal example below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ % Set options for ``listing'':
language=C++,
commentstyle=,
keywordstyle=,
identifierstyle=,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
breaklines=false,
frame=,
showstringspaces=false
}
\lstset{moredelim=[is][\bfseries]{***}{***}}

\begin{document}

This works:

 \begin{lstlisting}
 this is a ***test***!
 \end{lstlisting}

This doesn't:

 \begin{lstlisting}
 "this is a ***test***!"
 \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the solution works then it's usual not only to accept the answer, but also to upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to add `morestring=*[b]"` to your `\lstset`. This redeclares the `"`...`"` string syntax, but the asterisk means that `listings` still applies its formatting inside of these strings.

Here's my code; since LaTeX [doesn't have a bold typewriter font by default](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33039/55879), I used italics instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ % Set options for ``listing'':
    language=C++,
    % ... same options ... 
    showstringspaces=false,
    morestring=*[b]"
}
\lstset{moredelim=[is][\itshape]{***}{***}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
this is a ***test***!
\end{lstlisting}
With quotes:
\begin{lstlisting}
"this is a ***test***!"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, there is a caveat: this redefinition means that `listings` applies *all* formatting inside strings, not just your new delimiter. For example, `this` is a C++ keyword, so if you use `\lstset{keywordstyle=\color{blue}}`, then `this` is colored inside quotes as well:

[image]

This might not be desired behavior. If so, you'll probably have to use something other than `moredelim`, such as `escapeinside`.